# Mark as duplicate because an answer matches 2 different questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Referring to [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291413/league-of-legends-client-beta-where-do-recordings-save-to?noredirect=1#comment414127_291413), mbomb007 suggest that the question should be marked as duplicate because [his/her answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20263/how-to-replay-a-league-of-legends-match/290083#290083) to an older post matches the "potential" dupe.

Should we mark it as duplicate even though the *questions* are different ?

Comment: Answers being out of date is never a reason to ask a new question, in my book. That said, we're currently undergoing a trial that suspends that reasoning. So, yes, it is a dupe, no, we're not going to dupe it.

Comment: So, it's considered a duplicate if the same answer applies to a number of questions in context. For example, a question about Skyrim asking why they can't get a follower and then a year later someone asks why an animal follower won't follow. If the answer to both entail the same bug it becomes a duplicated question on grounds that the method of solvency is the same? Does that then mean the onus of research prior to asking becomes greater and therefore enforcible?